# Bind telnetd to specific IP on AIX 5.3?

Tags: aix, telnet, inetd

Is it possible to bind telnetd to a specific IP on AIX 5.3?  I know telnet is evil.  Unfortunately, we have to have it listening on one interface for a specific application, but I want to make sure that's the only interface/IP that it's listening on.

I have been searching all over the net and have found some advice for Linux, but it doesn't appear to be applicable to AIX.

Full disclosure: I am not the server admin, but I am working closely with them and am familiar with *nix.

Add: This is an internal server, which is connected to two different vlans.  This is NOT connected to the Internet(!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

man telnetd writes it is working with inetd. inetd on AIX doesn't see to accept IP in service name (like OpenBSD does for example). use TCP wrappers to define who can connect to your telnetd or use filter rules (lsfilt, chfilt, mkfilt) if you cannot use external firewall.